# Session data corrupted in django

Tags: python, django, session

Every time when I'm going to my signup page, I'm receiving this error

```
Session data corrupted
```

when I'm trying to signup anyway, POST request status is 302, but User is still created, but didn't save any email to registered user.

Why I'm getting that error and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

Sorry for getting late to this post, but by any chance, did you change the SECRET_KEY variable on your project? sessions used to be cyphered using this salt, so if you changed it you have corrupted all your sessions, but don't worry! is not a big deal, the worst-case scenario is for the sessions that were existing before this, those will need to log-in again, and that's it ;)

Comment: make sure that your is not randomly like this
SECRET_KEY = get_random_string(50, chars)

Comment: Also worth clearing all existing cookies for your Django site to stop seeing this message.

Answer (score 8):

You are getting this error because of this line: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py#L109

Apparently, there's something went terribly wrong with encryption of session data.

How to fix it? I'm not sure, I have a couple of ideas though:

- Do you use a custom session class?
- Do you use your Django session in another project?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes this problem happens when you open two different projects on the same runtime.

So first, stop your server, close completely and exit.

Now open your server again and start your current project on a fresh runtime.

Answer (score 3):

I was working in local and fixed the "session data corrupted" issue by deleting the cookies of my browser for 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

This sometimes happens because of your secret key in `settings.py`.

If you've set up a `get_random_key()` function to get a new key every time you reload the server (this is generally for production), then every time you update something in your code, the server autoreload will restart opening your files and of course restart the `settings.py` with a new key. That's how the data session get corrupted.

**For me I just set a key myself. You can let the default key be generated by django.**

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
import base64
import hashlib
import hmac
import json

def session_utoken(msg, secret_key, class_name='SessionStore'):
    key_salt = "django.contrib.sessions" + class_name
    sha1 = hashlib.sha1((key_salt + secret_key).encode('utf-8')).digest()
    utoken = hmac.new(sha1, msg=msg, digestmod=hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
    return utoken


def decode(session_data, secret_key, class_name='SessionStore'):
    encoded_data = base64.b64decode(session_data)
    utoken, pickled = encoded_data.split(b':', 1)
    expected_utoken = session_utoken(pickled, secret_key, class_name)
    if utoken.decode() != expected_utoken:
        raise BaseException('Session data corrupted "%s" != "%s"',
                            utoken.decode(),
                            expected_utoken)
    return json.loads(pickled.decode('utf-8'))

s = Session.objects.get(session_key=session_key)
decode(s.session_data, 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'))
```

credit to: http://joelinoff.com/blog/?p=920

Comment: how are you suppose to use this? do this functions belong in a middleware or something else? the link page is empty