# Django Admin Keeps Logging me Out

Tags: javascript, python, django, cookies

I'm using the development server, logging in at `/admin/`, and that much works just fine.  Then I can click on an admin item, such as groups: `/admin/auth/group/`.  And then I see in the JavaScript console:

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

And this is coming from:

`?next=/admin/jsi18n/:1`

In the network tab, I see that the request to `/admin/jsi18n/` has a status code of 302, which has been redirected for some reason and which shows the request cookie (appears valid), and the response cookie (now empty).

What am I doing wrong here?

Here are my `settings.py` cookie variables:

```
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = 'tokenname_csrftoken'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = CSRF_COOKIE_NAME
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = CSRF_COOKIE_NAME
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

All cookie names need to be unique.  Makes sense of course.

Changing `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` to `'tokenname_sessionid'`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-name

Answer (score 2):

I've been having this problem recently as well but the cause was a different one than what was suggested in the accepted answer. It took me 2 days to figure this one out, hope this would help someone with a similar issue.

I had the `SECRET_KEY` set this way:

```
from django.core.management.utils import get_random_secret_key

SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('APP_SECRET_KEY', default=get_random_secret_key())
```

and, since the `APP_SECRET_KEY` environment variable was not set, and since I was rebuilding the app in the docker, a new secret was generated every time.

**Solution:** make sure your secret key does not change as it affects Django session validation.

References:

- [Session data corrupted in django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39729372/771848)

Comment: I did something to correct for that before.  I used a docker entrypoint to check for a volumized config file, and if it didn't exist, I generated salts for the persisted config file: https://github.com/lagtv/lagtv/blob/c2d0deed785a045dbf0a60e1215d101598592628/docker-entrypoint.sh#L5-L12

Comment: I had this problem running a django app on heroku with the `SECRET_KEY=` code suggested in their `python-getting-started` project. It doesn't make sense to me for this to be the cause of session corruption after just 2 or 3 clicks around without any redeployments happening, but setting a static SECRET_KEY with `heroku config:set` solved the issue for me.