# Session data corrupted in Django session

Tags: django, django-sessions

I have an application which using Django 2.0 and I'm facing with an issue about session data today. (`SECRET_KEY` is a static string, and consistent among the app so this might not is the issue)

The command I've tried is:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
session = Session.objects.first()

session.get_decoded()
# Session data corrupted
# {}
```

Even when I clear all the sessions, login again for a new session but still facing the same issue. I really want to read the session from the backend using `manage.py shell` and those script above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38970832/session-data-corrupted-in-django).